# MySQL Prepared Statement Error

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

Using MySQL 5.5.31

See the SQL below:

```
set @auto_table = 'MyTableName';
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `?` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';
EXECUTE stmt USING @auto_table;
```

The error message from MySQL:

```
Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE
```

I have tried to change the 2nd line to be:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE ? AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';
```

Then the error message is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AUTO_INCREMENT = 1' at line 1
```

Comment: Placeholders can only be used where expressions are allowed, not in place of table or column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE ' + @auto_table + ' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';
EXECUTE stmt
```

Just watch out for SQL injection.  If @auto_table comes from a user, this won't be safe.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for because I wanted to use variables like this `EXECUTE stmt USING @auto_table;` and your answer forces me to re-prepare the statement each time. If no one comes up with a better solution in the next few days I will award you the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelIrey Check out the docs at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/prepare.html Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

I think your error lies here:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `?` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';
```

Missing ` before the 1

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE `?` AUTO_INCREMENT = `1`';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you need quotes around `1`? It's an integer.

Comment: I can't explain properly, but it's the way I've learnt PHP/MySQL, to surround strings/integers with quotes.

Comment: You can surround integers with quotes, because the string will get coerced when necessary. But you never _need_ to do this.

Comment: Well like I said - I hope it helps, in some cases I've found myself not putting quotes around integers and it produces an error - Theres no need for downvoting.

Comment: I downvoted because it's clear that your answer won't help with the real problem, which is that you can't use a `?` placeholder for the table name. Read the error message, it says the syntax error is at the `?`. I also challenge you to provide an example of a query where putting quotes around an integer fixes an error.